# Why reply to the comment is not displaying? Python Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to add some functionality that would allow a reply to the comment and display that reply underneath the comment but after trying everything I am unable to see the
reply being displayed to the comment. There are no errors showing so I can't really figure it out. I am guessing something is not right in the template? Please find the codes below. Hope that is all it requires to get me some help.

MODELS: comment model & reply model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    """comments for Post model"""

    comment_post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                     related_name='comment_for_post', null=True, default='')
    comment_text = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Reverse the Comment to the url once action
        has been taken with primary key to direct back to details page"""
        return reverse('posts:post_details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_text


class Reply(models.Model):
    """add reply to commnets"""
    reply_comment = models.ForeignKey(
        Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default='', related_name='comment_reply')
    reply_text = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.reply_text
```

VIEWS: reply to comment view

```
@login_required
def reply_to_comment(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(models.Comment, pk=pk)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ReplyCommentForm(request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            reply = form.save(commit=False)
            reply.reply_comment = comment
            reply.save()
            return redirect('posts:post_details', pk=comment.pk)

    else:
        form = forms.ReplyCommentForm()

    return render(request, 'posts/reply_comment_form.html', context={'form': form})
```

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('post_list/', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('user/<str:username>/', views.UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user_posts'),
    path('create/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('details/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_details'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>/', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('update/<int:pk>/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
    path('<str:category>/', views.CategoryPostListView.as_view(),
         name='category_posts'),
    path('posts/<int:pk>/comment', views.add_comment_to_post,
         name='post_comment_list'),
    path('delete_comment/<int:pk>/',
         views.CommentDeleteView.as_view(), name='delete_comment'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/reply/', views.reply_to_comment, name='reply'),
```

TEMPLATE:

```
          <div class='container'>
            {% for reply in comment.comment_reply.all %}
            <br>
            {% if  object.author == user %}
            <div class="">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <p >{{reply.reply_text}}</p>
                        <p class='text-capitalize'>From {{user.username}} on {{comment.date_posted|date:'d-M-y'}}.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                </div>
                {%else %}
                <div class="">

                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p >{{reply.reply_text|safe}}</p>
                            <p class='text-capitalize'>From {{user.username}} on {{comment.date_posted|date:'d-M-y'}}.</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the code below:

```
context={'form': form, 'comment': comment}
```

Comment: Tried, not doing anything. It seems like the template is not responding at all to the query.

Comment: @Ram this is the template you published? reply_comment_form.html, and  {% if  object.author == user %} author where is on your model?

Comment: class Post(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    text = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                null=True, choices=CHOICES)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

Comment: @Ram {% if  reply.author == request.user %}

Comment: No, it's not working. Thanks for trying tho